# Alternately add uppercase and lowercase letters?

Tags: python

I am working on a task for a beginner python course. Task is to take first uppercase letter and then lowercase letter and all over again.

this is input string:

```
"ifeFemFEkej83FkW"
```

and this should be output string:

```
FeFkFkW
```

friend and I came up with this solution, but it looks a little bit complicated, and I was wondering if there is maybe one-line solution or regular expression for some part of the code? Or maybe some different approach to the task. Thank you for your help.

```
str_a = "ifeFemFEkej83FkW"
new = ""
upper_case = True

for i in str_a:
    if "A" < i < "Z" and upper_case == True:
        new += i
        upper_case = False
    elif "a" < i < "z" and upper_case == False:
        new += i
        upper_case = True

print(new)
```

Comment: You could bring up imports and the standard library if you use string.ascii_uppercase and string.ascii_lowercase. You might want to teach it as a function, so you can show a test case. It could be a good time to introduce "in" if they're ready for sets or know big-O, but maybe not. And iterables are pretty important, but might be a bit soon for that, too.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to simplify it, using the `isupper()` function and the fact that you can always flip a bool to its opposite with `not`:

```
str_a = "ifeFemFEkej83FkW"
new = ""
upper_case = True

for i in str_a:
    if i.isupper() == upper_case:
        new += i
        upper_case = not upper_case

print(new)
```

And here's an approach with `itertools.groupby`.  This would be a pretty clean one-liner if not for the requirement of dropping initial lowercase letters:

```
import itertools

str_a = "ifeFemFEkej83FkW"

new = ''.join(next(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(str_a, str.isupper))
new = new if new[0].isupper() else new[1:]

print(new)
```

Comment: Pretty good, as long as everything is upper or lower. There might be an issue if e.g. numbers sneak in. Maybe chain a filter (which can remove the initial lowercase as well)?

Comment: `list(g)[0]` == `next(g)`, +1 still, mainly for the first solution :)